# Desktop or Offline Web App?

Tags: html, desktop-application, offline

I am building an application for a friend's event company. The software will only be used by a handful of people who run the events.

These are the essential requirements:

- The software will capture basic data input regarding the event and
  competitors.
- The software will need to work offline - an Internet connection
  cannot be guaranteed in venues.
- The software will locally store data which is to be synced to a
  remote database when an Internet connection is available.
- The software will display a second window sent to a projector screen and displaying updates 
  to the audience.
- The software will need to record data via a serial port for each event.

Though this might traditionally be a desktop application, I think there are good reasons for trying to build something like as a web app namely:

- Easier for me to build / maintain / test.
- Cheaper (.NET would be my first port of call for desktop but I heard Microsoft are
  abandoning VS Express for Windows 8).
- Platform independent - if an onsite laptop failure occurs, the ability to use another
  machine without installing and configuring the software is available, as is the possibility 
  of future hardware upgrades.

As I have not yet used the offline capabilities of HTML5. I'm wondering are there any caveats before going down this route - is a desktop app better, or another solution?

(I know I'd have to create a Java Applet for the serial port communication as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310643/how-to-read-from-serial-port-in-a-webpage).)

Comment: VS Express 2012 is available for Windows 8: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Comment: thanks I read that they would be discontinuing no-cost development - see [here](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/05/no-cost-desktop-software-development-is-dead-on-windows-8/) - but they may  have reneged on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to communicate with hardware I wouldn't bother with HTML5 and possibly Java applets. Just go with a desktop application.

Comment: thanks - are you able to provide any specifics on why?