# weighing scale integration with remote php program

Tags: serial-port, client-side

I've developed a billing screen in php that is hosted in a linux server. browser renders this page in the local machine where a weighing machine is connected.What's the best and fastest way to get the weighing machine reading from the remote server's program?I'm able to get the output of the weighing machine as a continuous stream in the client machine.. but the program is in the server and i need to access this continuous streaming there.. is there a way? The db is in mysql.

Comment: How does the scale connect to the client computer? How does it provide measurements? What is getting weighed?  Is there human intervention here? Will humans tell the computer when to take a measurement?  What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: *scale is connected to client m/c via serial port.The weighing m/c sends continuous data(weight) to the serial port. for now when a human presses enter key a php script calls  linux command "cat /dev/ttyS0" . this returns a stream of values which is exploded to get the final reading.this works fine when files are in client machine . now if the files are moved to the remote server, how should i change this

Comment: I'm editing this question's tags because it has nothing to do with php or mysql.  You're going to need some client-side software to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310643/how-to-read-from-serial-port-in-a-webpage