# Having a web application access a service directly without a server

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, serial-port, windows-services

For my job, I am doing research on finding a means on how a web application running locally from file:\ in IE11, created with either HTML5 or Javascript, can access the raw data or listen to a computer's serial port being sent out from a windows service or proxy.  The situation is that We have a proxy designed to collect data from a computer's serial port and it will send that data outward on our network to the local host.

What we want our web application to do is to catch that data the proxy is sending out directly from the service on the computer, removing the need to have the proxy send the data to a server and having the web application collect the data from a server.  So far googling the solution has been difficult.  Does anyone know the solution to our problem or knows where to find the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicate with the serial port from client web browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114474/communicate-with-the-serial-port-from-client-web-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Lazy people, why don't you use Google search bar (!?!)...

Here: https://github.com/garrows/browser-serialport

Note: You cannot use this in a Web page, i.e. cannot put it on a Web server. And it is supported only by Chrome.

Comment: What specific search keys did you use to this similar solution?  I have been searching for this solution in google for a while and been having difficulty finding the solution.  I have so far I have found a few ideas, unfortunately they have not been able to solve the issue we are having.

Comment: "serial port in browser" - first link was the one in the answer